# How to install crontab on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I am familiar to setup the cron scheduler using `crontab -e` command on my `centos`. But today I found one of my `centos` servers doesn't have this command

I have tried to install this using `yum install crontab` but no luck. Then I tried `yum install crontabs` and it installed something

```
=============================================================================
 Package                 Arch       Version          Repository        Size 
=============================================================================
Updating:
 crontabs                noarch     1.10-11.el5      base              7.0 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================
Install      0 Package(s)         
Update       1 Package(s)         
Remove       0 Package(s)         

Total download size: 7.0 k
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

But still the `crontab` command doesn't work. If I do `cat /etc/crontab` then it shows below thing

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
40 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
54 1 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
14 3 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
38 1 16 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

What should I do to have `crontab` on that particular server? I am using `CentOS release 5.2 (Final)`.

grep on cron shows:

```
[root~]# ps -ef | grep cron
root     24022 24001  0 19:07 pts/1    00:00:00 grep cron
```

starting cron service returns:

```
[root~]# service cron start
cron: unrecognized service
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

As seen in [Install crontab on CentOS](http://blog.inticol.com/2013/03/install-crontab-on-centos-6.html), the crontab package in CentOS is `vixie-cron`. Hence, do install it with:

```
yum install vixie-cron
```

And then start it with:

```
service crond start
```

To make it persistent, so that it starts on boot, use:

```
chkconfig crond on
```

---

On CentOS 7 you need to use `cronie`:

```
yum install cronie
```

On CentOS 6 you can install `vixie-cron`, but the real package is `cronie`:

```
yum install vixie-cron
```

and

```
yum install cronie
```

In both cases you get the same output:

```
.../...
==================================================================
 Package         Arch       Version         Repository      Size
==================================================================
Installing:
 cronie          x86_64     1.4.4-12.el6    base             73 k
Installing for dependencies:
 cronie-anacron  x86_64     1.4.4-12.el6    base             30 k
 crontabs        noarch     1.10-33.el6     base             10 k
 exim            x86_64     4.72-6.el6      epel            1.2 M

Transaction Summary
==================================================================
Install       4 Package(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for cronie, which is the important part for 7.x

Comment: Note that on 6.x `yum install crontabs` will also install cronie, cronie-anacron, and exim. Be sure to remember the service is `crond` and it will need to be started (and `chkconfig enable on`).