# should we use cron if we are using delay in our program...?

Tags: php, api, cron, delay

So i have written a program to call API from a website each 20 minutes. i"ve done this by giving the sleep() function in php.
i have given this delay inside a while loop. how can i execute the same function using cron?
 this is the while loop..

```
<?php
@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1200);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
//code;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {

    //code;
    if(sleep(1200)!=0)
    {
        echo "sleep failed script terminating"; 
        break;
    }
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Use crontab. `*/20 * * * * php -f path/to/script.php`

Comment: Your question title doesn't really match the question body... Are you asking **how** you should do this or **whether** you should do this?

Comment: @hd:Can i call a crontab inside that while loop..? instead of the sleep() function?

Comment: No. You need to use `crontab -e` and set it up. Remove all the `sleep()` logic within your script.

Comment: @lix:I'm asking whether we should use cron instead of sleep().

Comment: @hd: ok..so if we are using crontab -e ,is the while loop being executed each 20 mins or the whole php file?

Comment: The whole file will be called every 20 minutes, executed by the cron.

Comment: is there any way that you suggest to execute the while loop only., after each 20 minutes..?

Comment: Better software design? What's needed to run the loop? You could pass an argument into the script and skip everything up to the loop if the argument is supplied.

Comment: @hd:i am doing a people search API in our script.So we are calling the API based on the entries that we already have in our database.We need to execute a delay for each entry to get the API response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the `sleep`, and use the cron.

- In your console type `crontab -e`
- Set up the following;

```
*/20 * * * * php -f path/to/script.php
```

- [Install crontab on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21802522/3000179)
- [Windows scheduled task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)
- [Add Jobs To cron Under Linux or UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)